# Android ServerSocket How to get the lan ip address of Server

Tags: android, serversocket

I used this piece of code because I am struggling to get the Lan (Wifi) ip address of a ServerSocket.

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = 
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();                          
enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) 
{
   InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
   if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
           ipAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
   }
}
}
```

The value of ipAddress is:

```
fe80::6a96:65a4:2cd8:bf8a%wlan0
```

How do I get the readable ip address from this? E.G.

```
192.18.1.10 Etc?
```

Comment: `fe80::6a96:65a4:2cd8:bf8a` is an IPv6 address. `192.18.1.10` is an IPv4 address. Also, have a look at the [`WifiInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo) class and its [`getIpAddress()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getIpAddress()) method

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet to get connected router's IP address. It will give you 
format similar to 192.168.0.10.

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 if (wifiManager.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
         DhcpInfo dhcpInfo = wifiManager.getDhcpInfo();
         int serverAddress = dhcpInfo.serverAddress;
         String routersIPAddress=String.format(Locale.US, "%d.%d.%d.%d", (serverAddress & 0xff), (serverAddress >> 8 & 0xff), (serverAddress >> 16 & 0xff), (serverAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
 }
```

Comment: That function always seems to give 192.168.1.254 on everything it's run on- any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you need? your question is  ambiguous. Where is your server running? Server is connected to router and android device is also connected router or there is peer to peer communication between android device and server.

Comment: I am looking to get the ip v4 address of the device on my lan.